# Different CSS for divs in jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I want to do an jQuery fade in and fade out in a loop such as [here in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/)

But I want to maintain different css positioning for each of the .trip elements, ie, the elements fading in and out.

For example with the element  `<div id="3" class="trip">Item3</div>` , I want to add positioning so that it displays left 200px when it fades in, such as in this css:

```
#3{position:absolute; left:200px;}
```

AND for another element

```
#2{position:absolute; left:100px;top:100px;}
```

With the current code in the jsfiddle, the elements are loaded in the same spot on the page.

I tried adding css to the different elements as I did above, but it still loads in the same place as in the jsfiddle.

How do I fix this?

Comment: IDs can't start with a number, FYI.

Comment: He's correct, if you add your CSS and change the ID's to div1 div2 and div3 it works just fine.

Comment: I used the ids to be in numeric format to count in the jquery loop. But I added it as class="trip one" etc, and used the css as .trip.one and now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can't start id's with a number in CSS. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/65/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one" class="trip">Item1</div>
    <div id="two" class="trip">Item2</div>
    <div id="three" class="trip">Item3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#two{position:absolute; left:100px;top:100px;}    
#three{position:absolute; left:200px;}
```

Comment: Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SaQXY/1/

Comment: HTML5 says you can start ID's with a number :D

Comment: @tymeJV IDs starting with numbers are perfectly valid in HTML5. Problem is, CSS selectors will not work correctly... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give margin for each ids

CSS:

```
#a2 { margin-left: 200px; }
#a3 { margin-left: 400px; }
```

HTML :

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="one" class="trip">Item1</div>
   <div id="two" class="trip">Item2</div>
   <div id="three" class="trip">Item3</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtmxN/66/)**

Answer (score 0):

Or you can give them margin dynamically , some thing like this:

```
function go() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).fadeIn(700, function() {
        $elem.css( { marginLeft :( (i+1) * 100)+ "px", marginRight :((i+1) * 100) + "px" } );
        $elem.eq(i % l).fadeOut(700, go);
        i++;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't start IDs with numbers. It's not valid.

However, if you *absolutely* have to (maybe it's not your HTML), you can give them CSS rules like so:

```
[id='2'] { margin-left:200px; }
[id='3'] { margin-left:400px; }
```

But, again, fix the ID names if you can. You'll have fewer issues.